# Using Fresco library of facebook in eclipse causes class not found exception

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, fresco

I am implementing a test app using fresco library in eclipse as shown in the [url](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html#_)
but it is not working fine and showing this error NoClassDefFound:Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/imagepipeline/core/ImagePipelineFactory; I have followed the same steps as specified in the above url.

can any one tell me why I am getting that error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please file an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this is

First import all the 5 projects namely drawee, fbcore, fresco, imagepipeline, and imagepipeline-okhttp in your workspace(All 5 are libs).

Now ,In eclipse right click on Your project Where you want to use Fresco lib (test app in your case)

Properties -> Android

Now add all the above 5 projects by clicking on add button. 
Clean once and run.